# Python Regular Expression group repetition within a repetition

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, repeat

I have a string and have to extract. The problem is I can't describe repetition within a repetition. So here is the code:

```
f = "Makimak-cg_mk_Mokarmi"
pattern = "([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+)((?:[-_]([a-z]{2}))+)"
mO = re.match(pattern, f)
print mO.groups()
```

And the result will be:

```
('Makimak', '-cg_mk', 'mk')
```

But I would like to get tuple like this:

```
('Makimak', '-cg_mk', 'cg', 'mk')
```

So there is a group "-cg_mk" which include a repetition of the two character pattern. But there is no thing like that:

```
[a-z]{2}+
```

The groups of the result give back only the last part of the repetition expressed here:

```
([a-z]{2})
```

My thought was that there should be a "+" too like this:

```
([a-z]{2})+
```

It gives the same result. The match object is generated, simply I can't get the groups that I want.

Comment: I doubt this is possible with a simple python regex using `re`.  AFAIK, all of the functions within `re` deal with *non-overlapping* occurances.  Catching overlapping occurances seems pretty daunting ...

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to have repetitions in the output? What other inputs should this work with?

Comment: I'm just curious what can I do with re modul. Is it possible to get the result I described above in one line. Of course I considered solution like F.J wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do this in two steps:

```
>>> f = "Makimak-cg_mk_Mokarmi"
>>> pattern = "([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+)((?:[-_][a-z]{2})+)"
>>> mO = re.match(pattern, f)
>>> print mO.groups() + tuple(re.split('[-_]', mO.group(2))[1:])
('Makimak', '-cg_mk', 'cg', 'mk')
```

This just captures the groups `('Makimak', '-cg_mk')`, and then combines this with the result of splitting the second group on occurrences of `-` or `_`.

If you always knew the exact number of two character patterns you could accomplish this with a lookahead, but it doesn't seem like that is known up front or you wouldn't need the repetition.